# Compare value previous\next value in df and correct it based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
**time**            **price**
1103                   5  
0010                   10
0100                   6
0201                   8
0015                   7
0400                   4
0900                   6
0800                   3
1000                   4
1140                   5
1400                   2
0030                   1
0112                   0

time = [1103,0010,0100,0201,0015,0400,0900,0800,1000,1140,1400,0030,0112]
price= [5,10,6,8,7,4,6,3,4,5,2,1,0]
```

Both the columns have **dtype object**.

I want to compare every time value to its previous and next value. If the value is greater than previous value and greater than next value (if the next value does not start with 00), I want the value to be replaced by previous value +100. So in our sample data the result will look like this:

```
**time**            **price**
1103                   5  
0010                   10
0100                   6
0201                   8
0015                   7
0400                   4
0500 (changed)         6
0800                   3
1000                   4
1140                   5
1400  (not changed)    2
0030                   1
0112                   0
```

Would appreciate some help with that, thanks.

Comment: Your output is the same as your input, or do i miss something?

Comment: The time value at index 6 has changed while at index 10 hasn't. I will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: It's interesting how your data is object, e.g string type but you want to increase it by `100` (numerical).

Comment: @QuangHoang the field later gets converted to time format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert `time` to integers for easy modification:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(int)

df.loc[df['time'].gt(df['time'].shift())      # greater than previous
       & df['time'].gt(df['time'].shift(-1))  # greater than next
       & df['time'].shift(-1).ge(100),        # next greater than 100
      'time'] = df['time'].shift(fill_value=0).add(100)

df['time'] = df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

Output:

```
    time price
0   1103     5
1   0010    10
2   0100     6
3   0201     8
4   0015     7
5   0400     4
6   0500     6
7   0800     3
8   1000     4
9   1140     5
10  1400     2
11  0030     1
12  0112     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made this:

```
df = dfd.to_dict() #dfd =  the old dataframe
l = []
for k in df['time']:
    l.append(df['time'][k])
for i in range(len(l)):
    try:
        if l[i] > l[i-1] and l[i] > l[i+1]:
            l[i] = l[i-1] + 100
    except IndexError:
        pass
for i in range(len(l)):
    df['time'][i] = l[i]
dfd = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The logic is to transform into dictionary, make the computations with easy classic python ways and then re-transform it to DataFrame